# Check for values passed to the view with the instance object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I add a value to an instance object in the controller, like so:

`@post = Post.new(published: false)`

I expected it to show up in the params, or SOMEWHERE in the server logs or SOMEWHERE inspecting the web console (the Net tab in FF).

But I cannot see it being transferred in any other way than by displaying it in a form field.

What alternative ways are there to debug instance object values?

Comment: Are you looking for `@post.inspect` ? There is a guide about debugging in Rails : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
<%= debug @post %>
```

in your view.